# Weird differential equation: $|f''(t)|=f(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find **ALL** functions $f: \mathbb{R} \to  \mathbb{R}$ of class $C^2$ such that for all $t \in \mathbb{R} $ we have $|f''(t)|=f(t)$.

Comment: Trigonometric functions ?

Comment: Where are you stuck? Some easy examples: $sin, cos, exp$

Comment: $f(t) = Ce^t$. Do you want them all?

Comment: @ctst OOps My bad..

Comment: I think you guys are underestimating the subtlety of the problem.

Comment: And in response to your comment immediately above, I think you, Joshua, are underestimating how to ask a good question.  You get back only what you put in...No effort? $\checkmark$, no source source given for the question?$\checkmark$, Written in the imperative (do, solve, find, evaluate, prove....)? $\checkmark$, No question asked? $\checkmark$, low-quality post? $\checkmark$ !

Comment: I@amWhy mostly use this site to post questions for which I have already found a solution because often I find messy, inelegant solutions and I'm hoping someone else can provide a clean proof. I don't see why you can't just read the statement of a problem and post a proof; it's quite annoying each time to post all of the work I've done in latex. I'm not here to prove I can solve the problem I'm here to ask if anyone else has a solution.

Comment: @amWhy: I don't understand why I can't just post a problem statement and then other people take it a nice problem and post a solution if they find one. This is how a lot of other math forums work I don't get why stack exchange is so picky about the way people ask questions.

Comment: @Joshua Benabou The spirit of the site is for people to get help from other people volunteering their time. It is not for the people to put their homework on the site and get it solved. And if you are not willing to spend time to put your attempts in latex (at least some steps of what you have done), why would you require other people to spent their own time to write Latex to help you?

Comment: Exactly, its people volunteering to answer - if they want to answer, then they'll do so; if they don't want to, they won't post an answer. I don't expect anyone to answer my question I just am hoping someone might share a nicer solution than the one I have found. And I'm thankful for those who do post answers. In any case, its (quite clearly) not a HW question...

Comment: That's why you should be polite with the people volunteering their time to help you. Regardless whether you like or not their solution. Should you write down what your difficulty is inside the question,  you would not have attracted low quality answers. Also your comments on my answer: "The first statement is already false." and "this doesn't work because the maximum $a$ might not exist." What about "could you clarify why the first statement is true?" and "I am not sure why the maximum $a$ exist, could you help me?" I for one don't care, but other people do.

Answer (score 5):

$f$ is non-negative and satisfies either $f''=f$ or $f''=-f$ which have the solutions $c_1e^x+c_2e^{-x}$ and $c_1\cos x+c_2\sin x$.

The second one cannot be solution, since it takes both negative and positive values, unless it is the trivial solution.

Then you solve for $c_1$ and $c_2$ which make $f$ non-negative on $\mathbb R$

EDIT: to address Joshua Benabou's objection regarding the brevity of the proof:

1) $f$ is a local minimum in its zeroes, so if $f(x_0)=0$ then $f(x_0)=f'(x_0)=f''(0)=0$

2) suppose that we have both $f''=f$ and $f''=-f$ for some points, so WLOG we assume that $f''(x_1)=f(x_1)>0$ and $f''(x_2)=-f(x_2)<0$ for some points $x_1<x_2$. Let $[x_2,a)$ be the maximal interval (maximum $a$), so that $f''(x)>0$ on $[x_1,a)$. By continuity we have $f''(a)=0=f(a)$. So on $[x_1,a]$ we have the equation $f''(x)=f(x)$ with the boundary condition $f(a)=f'(a)=0$. The only solution of this equation is $f=0$, contradiction with $f(x_1)>0$

3) The non-negativity of $f$ implies $c_1,c_2\ge 0$, so all the solutions of this equation are $f(x)=c_1e^x+c_2e^{-x}$, $c_1,c_2\ge 0$

Comment: The first statement is already false. You have made the problem easier than it is.

Comment: What I wrote is just a summary of the proof. You may argue that I haven't proved my first statement, but not that it is false. I have not underestimated the problem, and I took into account the possibility of existence of "stitched" solutions of both $f$ and $-f$, but such solutions cannot exist.

Comment: @Joshua Benabou I updated my answer to address your concerns.

Comment: this doesn't work because the maximum $a$ might not exist. That's kind of the whole point of this problem...

Comment: What makes you say so? What about $a=\inf\{x:x\ge x_0 \text{ and } f''(x)\le 0\}$?

Answer (score 3):

The difficult point seem  to show that we can suppose that either ($f(t)=f^{\prime\prime}(t)$ for all $t$ ), or ($f(t)=-f^{\prime\prime}(t)$ for all $t$ ), as we have only that for all $t$, we have ($f(t)=f^{\prime\prime}(t)$ or $f(t)=-f^{\prime\prime}(t)$).

A solution, (perhaps there is simpler)

a) Suppose that there exists $x_0\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x_0)=0$. Then at $x_0$, $f \geq 0$ has a local minimum, and hence $f^{\prime}(x_0)=0$. Now from $$f^{\prime}(x)-f^{\prime}(x_0)=\int_{x_0}^x f^{\prime\prime}(t)dt$$
we get that $\displaystyle |f^{\prime}(x)|\leq \int_{x_0}^x f(t)dt$ for $x\geq x_0$.

For $x>x_0$ there exists a $c\in ]x_0,x[$ such that $f(x)-f(x_0)=(x-x_0)f^{\prime}(c)$. We get easily that for $x\geq x_0$, we have
$$f(x)\leq (x-x_0)\int_{x_0}^c f(t)dt\leq  (x-x_0)\int_{x_0}^x f(t)dt$$
If $\displaystyle h(x)=\exp(-(x-x_0)^2/2)\int_{x_0}^x f(t)dt$, we see that the derivative of $h$ is negative for $x\geq x_0$. As $h(x)\geq 0$ for $x\geq x_0$, and $h(x_0)=0$, we get $h(x)=0$ for $x\geq x_0$, and it is easy to see that this imply $f(x)=0$ for $x\geq x_0$.

b) Note that $f_1(x)=f(-x)$ satisfy also the differential equation, and that $f_1(x_1)=0$ for $x_1=-x_0$. By a) we have $f_1(x)=0$ for $x\geq x_1$, and this show that $f(x)=0$ for $x\leq x_0$. Hence $f$ is the zero function.

c) We may suppose to finish that $f(x)\not =0$ for all $x$; as $f^{\prime\prime}$ is continuous, it has a constant sign, and we have only to find the solutions of $f(x)=f^{\prime\prime}(x)$ and of $f(x)=-f^{\prime\prime}(x)$ that are $>0$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:   $f(x)=e^x, f'(x)=f(x)$.

Comment: That was only one half was it?